# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

After reading most of the thread related to this issue but my problem not get resolved.

I have a running Java Project A. Now i created another project B and add the jar of project A. Project B is web project and on index.jsp i call a class from the project A jar. while i tried to run the jsp file i got this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Common cannot be resolved to a type
13: <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
14: </head>
15: <%   
16:       Common objCommon= new Common();
17:       String comboS = objCommon.comboValueReturn();
18:      
19: %>
```

My JSP is like:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Properties"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="com.au.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="com.au.bean.*;" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
<%   
  Common objCommon= new Common();
  String comboS = objCommon.comboValueReturn();

%>
```

I checked there is only one Servlet-api.jar in  tomcat bin. 
Jar is added in web-inf/lib.  Tried by putting build-path
JRE version is same of both project..

Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

itin

Comment: The reason that it can't find `Common` is that it is not available in the class path. If I understand it correctly, you have created a JAR file from **project A** and added it to `WEB-INF/lib` folder of **project B**?

Comment: yes. correct. if i try to call Common class from Project B main.java then it works.. but getting error from jsp

Comment: Then make sure that `Common` is actually is in the JAR file and secondly make sure that the correct package path is declared in your JSP. Any JAR file in `WEB-INFO/lib` should be available in the class path. What is the package path of class `Common`?

Comment: all these things are correct. package com.au.bean; it is notgiving any class not found error its means it is getting the Common class. Not sure about this "Any JAR file in WEB-INFO/lib should be available in the class path.."

Comment: What I meant was the jar files in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder are automatically added to the class path.

Comment: What is the folder structure inside the jar?

Comment: src->com.au->.classes